# how to set the antd table page size in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm using antd table  for data viewing and used separate antd pagination .I want to set  page size of the antd table how to achive it.I'm not using default table pagination in antd table

```
 <Pagination defaultCurrent={1} total={data.length} pageSize={2} onChange={this.setPaginationData}/>

 <Table
      rowKey={data._id}
      columns={this.columns1}
      rowSelection={this.rowSelection}
      expandedRowRender={(record, index, indent, expanded) =>
                        this.expanding(record, expanded)                         
                    }
      // pagination={{defaultCurrent:1, total:data.length, pageSize:2,position:'top'}}

      onExpand={this.onExpand}
      dataSource={data} />
```

please help...

Comment: can you approve correct answer?

Answer (score 15):

You can simply pass an `Pagination`object:

```
<Table pagination={{ pageSize: 6}} />
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to set page size without setting the pagination, so your only option is to limit the `data`:

```
const PAGE_SIZE = 5;
<Table dataSource={data.slice(PAGE_SIZE)} />;
```

Refer to [Array#slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Comment: Hey when I select  parent row through selection column ,along with parent I want to select child row of that selected row

Comment: I dont think it's related to what you asked, try just posting another question

Comment: Posted a diffrent question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57974511/select-child-rows-when-we-select-on-the-parent-row-using-rowselection-in-antd-ta