# Select child rows when we select on the parent row using rowSelection in antd table

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm trying rowselection reactjs using antd table.I'm trying this one
[ant-components-table-demo-expand-children](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-expand-children)

when I select parent row it must select child rows of that parent (it should tick mark the child rows).

```
this.rowSelection = {
    onSelect: (record, selected, selectedRows) => this.onSelectChange(record, selected, selectedRows),
    onSelectAll: (selected, selectedRows, changeRows) => this.allRowsSelected(selected, selectedRows, changeRows)
};


<Table
    rowKey={data._id}
    columns={this.columns1}
    rowSelection={this.rowSelection}
    expandedRowRender={(record, index, indent, expanded) =>
        this.expanding(record, expanded)                         
    }
    onExpand={this.onExpand}
    dataSource={data}
/>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit on using SET instead of ARRAY. Im new to ES6, please help me understand the difference. Hope this could be an opportunity to get clear with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: select-all-children-checkboxes]

When you select a `parent` node, you can get the `children` nodes from `onSelect` function. Similarly, You can get all the nodes when you `select/deselect` from `onSelectAll` function.

You need to store those `keys` of selected `parent` node and it's children nodes in `state`.

To `select/deselect` checkboxes, you need to set/unset those `keys` to `selectedRowKeys` like so: `selectedRowKeys: Array.from(selectedCBKeys)` (selectedCBKeys = parent key + it's children keys)

```
const rowSelection = {
      selectedRowKeys: Array.from(selectedCBKeys),

      onChange: (selectedRowKeys, selectedRows) => {},

      onSelect: (record, selected, selectedRows) => {
        this.getKey(record);
      }, 

      onSelectAll: (selected, selectedRows, changeRows) => {
        changeRows.map(item => this.getKey(item));
      }
    };
```

**How to get all the keys of children nodes of a parent tree?**

Just **recursively traverse** the parent tree. I collected all the `keys` like so:

```
getKey = data => {
    this.storeKey(data.key); //it just stores the key in "state"
    if (data.children) {
      data.children.map(item => this.getKey(item));
    }
  };
```

This is how I stored all the keys. I used [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

```
 state = {
    selectedCBKeys: new Set()
  };

  storeKey = key => {

    //If the key is already present in "state" just delete it. 
     //It helps in toggling the checkboxes.. right?

    if (this.state.selectedCBKeys.has(key)) { 
      const newSet = this.state.selectedCBKeys;
      newSet.delete(key);
      this.setState({
        selectedCBKeys: newSet
      });
      return;
    }

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      selectedCBKeys: prevState.selectedCBKeys.add(key)
    }));
  };
```

**App.js**

```
import { Table } from "antd";

const columns = [
  {
    title: "Name",
    dataIndex: "name",
    key: "name"
  },
  {
    title: "Age",
    dataIndex: "age",
    key: "age",
    width: "12%"
  },
  {
    title: "Address",
    dataIndex: "address",
    width: "30%",
    key: "address"
  }
];

const data = [
  {
    key: 1,
    name: "John Brown sr.",
    age: 60,
    address: "New York No. 1 Lake Park",
    children: [
      {
        key: 11,
        name: "John Brown",
        age: 42,
        address: "New York No. 2 Lake Park"
      },
      {
        key: 12,
        name: "John Brown jr.",
        age: 30,
        address: "New York No. 3 Lake Park",
        children: [
          {
            key: 121,
            name: "Jimmy Brown",
            age: 16,
            address: "New York No. 3 Lake Park"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    key: 2,
    name: "Joe Black",
    age: 32,
    address: "Sidney No. 1 Lake Park"
  }
];

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    selectedCBKeys: new Set()
  };

  storeKey = key => {
    if (this.state.selectedCBKeys.has(key)) {
      const newSet = this.state.selectedCBKeys;
      newSet.delete(key);
      this.setState({
        selectedCBKeys: newSet
      });
      return;
    }
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      selectedCBKeys: prevState.selectedCBKeys.add(key)
    }));
    console.log("new keys: ", key);
  };

  getKey = data => {
    this.storeKey(data.key);
    if (data.children) {
      data.children.map(item => this.getKey(item));
    }
  };
  render() {
    const { selectedCBKeys } = this.state;
    // rowSelection objects indicates the need for row selection
    const rowSelection = {
      selectedRowKeys: Array.from(selectedCBKeys),
      onChange: (selectedRowKeys, selectedRows) => {
        console.log(
          `selectedRowKeys: ${selectedRowKeys}`,
          "selectedRows: ",
          selectedRows
        );
      },
      onSelect: (record, selected, selectedRows) => {
        this.getKey(record);
      },
      onSelectAll: (selected, selectedRows, changeRows) => {
        console.log(
          "onSelectAll: ",
          selected,
          " selectedRows: ",
          selectedRows,
          " changeRows: ",
          changeRows
        );
        // selectedRows.map(item => this.getKey(item));
        changeRows.map(item => this.getKey(item));
      }
    };
    return (
      <div className="parent">
        <Table
          columns={columns}
          rowSelection={rowSelection}
          dataSource={data}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-57974511-table-expand-children) on stackblitz. Let me know,

Answer (score 3):

From version `4.4.0`, a **much simpler one-liner solution** is to set [`checkStrictly`](https://ant.design/components/table/#rowSelection) to `false`.

See more [here](https://ant.design/components/table/) for both demo and its specification, *(`Ctrl`+`F` and search for the keyword "checkStrictly", both demo and its documentation are there)*

```
rowSelection={{
  checkStrictly: false,
  onChange: (_, selectedRows) => {
    setSelectedRows(selectedRows);
  },
}}
```